# Restart without shutdown on Windows

Tags: windows, shutdown, reboot

Is there a way to restart without shutting down first on Windows? On Linux this is possible using [kexec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) and serves to minimize downtime. What happens is that one does not pass through the bootloader stage and no BIOS is seen.

Comment: No it is not possible with Windows, as far as I am aware.

Comment: You could with win98, feature was removed in W2K and up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible. As Moab pointed out in the comments, it used to be possible in Windows 9x.

That used to work by unloading Windows, going to the DOS environment, and reloading Windows again (if I recall correctly, one could simply type in `exit` at the command prompt to get Windows to reload).

*Disclosure: I wrote ShutOff 2000, so I've been fiddling around with ways to shut down Windows since 1999. I don't claim to know all there is about it, though.*